# Как сделать длинный border при клике на навигацию

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, значит проблема в чём, хочу зделать такой border, чтобы при применении id `id="active"` этот бордер, применялся к другим пунктам меню. По оформлению(хоть этого и не видно при запуске кода ниже), мне удалось сделать такой бордер через `after` но как видите он абсолютно спозиционирован и не применяется к другим пунктам меню при изменении id. Какие есть варианты решения такой вот проблемки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.sf-menu {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    display: flex;
}

.sf-menu:after {
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.4);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 14%;
}

.sf-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 45px;
}

.sf-menu li a {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sf-menu .fab {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#active:after {
    content: '';
    height: 5px;
    width: 5%;
    background-color: #11749e;
    position: absolute;
    left: 30.5%;
    top: 13.5%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sf-menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Extensions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
       </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Вообще не понял ничего...

Comment: @Air Ну я старался понятно объяснить, так то мне ответ дали

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно и без `::after`, и вместо `border` использовать `box-shadow`

```js
// Просто для визуализации

$('.nav a').on('click', function() {
  $('.nav a').attr('id', '');
  $(this).attr('id', 'active')
});
```

```css
.nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a#active {
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 0 0 #07f inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#" id="active">index 1</a>
  <a href="#">index 2</a>
  <a href="#">index 3</a>
  <a href="#">index 4</a>
  <a href="#">index 5</a>
</div>
```

Если нужен именно ваш вариант, то вот:

```css
.sf-menu {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  display: flex;
}

.sf-menu:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 14%;
}

.sf-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.sf-menu li a {
  display: block;
  /* ДОБАВИТЬ ЭТО */
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  /* ДОБАВИТЬ ЭТО */
}

.sf-menu .fab {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

#active:after {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  /* ДОБАВИТЬ ЭТО */
  background-color: #11749e;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* ДОБАВИТЬ ЭТО */
  bottom: -5px;
  /* ДОБАВИТЬ ЭТО */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sf-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Extensions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @ чего второй вариант не работает?

Comment: @Air, работает он) Просто "демонстрации" как в первом нету)